# DataTable incredibely slow with IE8

Tags: performance, datatable, internet-explorer-8

I use Datatable on a table, I load the data from a JS array (so it is server-sided). In order to load a list of 350 rows - each rows of 10 column - IE8 requires more than 10s where filter and sorting are disabled.

https://datatables.net/faqs/index says that it can handles thousend of rows.

```
                   $("#table").DataTable({
                        "data" : data,
                        "processing" : true,
                        "filter": false,
                        "orderClasses": false,
                        "ordering": false,
                        "deferRender" : true,
                        "columns": columns,
                    });
```

(data is my list of rows and columns the columns description).

Comment: what version of Datatable are you using?

Comment: Last one: 1.10.9. I only include the main JS and CSS files (jquery.datatables.js and jquery.dataTables.css)

Comment: I think the question should be expressed as "**IE8 incredibely slow when using dataTables**".  While the table is rendered IE8 is recalculating <td> widths etc too, over and over - the problem is that IE8 tends to end up with very large floating points numbers (large as many numbers after the comma) - slowing the performance down.

Comment: Not possible to avoid recalculating all these things?

Comment: A clue is to use the scroller widget but I can't make it work (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652947/datatable-with-scroller-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the slowness is coming from the initialization of the JS array that I pass to construct the table.
I used a PHP script and iterated over each row / column that I wanted like:

```
data[$row][$col] = 'xxx';
....
```

The only way I found to make it work really faster is to really build the js array in one pass like:

```
var data = [
  <?php foreach($rows as $row)?>
  {  <?php foreach($cols as $n=>$col?>
     '<?php echo $n?>': '<?php echo $col?>',
];
```

This way for a 1 000 lines tables I pass from 15s to 2s with sorting and filtering activated.

Carreful: when IE8 sees an array like

```
[{'coucou': 'hi'},]
```

Then it builds an array:

```
    [{'coucou': 'hi'}, undefined]
```

That datatable doesn't like